# Regex Expression - Match test expressions for jasmine and karma

Tags: regex, unit-testing

i need to create a regex expression that match all **.ts (typescripts files) but doesn't allow karma and jasmine test files: **.spec.ts and **.e2e.ts

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$).*\.ts$`

Comment: This works! Hi Wiktor, you should write your regex as an answer to allow me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$).*\.ts$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$)` - the string cannot end with `.e2e.ts` nor with `.spec.ts` (this is a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern matches: any 0+ chars as many as possible (`.*`) up to the last `.` (`\.`), `e2e` or `spec` (`(e2e|spec)`), again a `.` and then `ts` at the end of the string (`$`))
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last
- `\.ts` - `.ts` literal char sequence
- `$` - end of string.